# Groovy Iterators: No signature of method: is applicable for argument types: (myFunction_closure1_closure3)

Tags: groovy, iterator, closures

I'm iterating over a set of string values and passing each to an external function like so:

```
List<String> myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

myArray.each() {
  myExternalFunction({it})
}
```

However, I'm getting the closure error above. Why is this happening? Does `{it}` evaluate to a `String` when it's inside the closure? Why is it passing the closure itself as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

myArray.each {
  myExternalFunction(it)
}
```

`myExternalFunction` excepts a String but with the present implementation `{it}` is a closure which is passed to the method. Hence the complain.

You can find more about [Closures in Groovy.](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_closures)